# Patch vs Put - When should which method be used?

Tags: http, request, http-headers, patch, put

Wikipedia says that the main difference between Put and Patch is that PUT sends the resource from the Uri. So `/model/id`. Then Patch will send in the body the data to modify as key / value over the uri `/model`.

> The main difference between the PUT and PATCH method is that the PUT
> method uses the request URI to supply a modified version of the
> requested resource which replaces the original version of the
> resource, whereas the PATCH method supplies a set of instructions to
> modify the resource. If the PATCH document is larger than the size of
> the new version of the resource sent by the PUT method then the PUT
> method is preferred.[1]

But what does Wiki mean by the sentence: "*If the PATCH document is larger than the new version of the resource sent by the PUT method, the PUT method is preferable*".

Answer (score 0):

It means that if the length of the set of instructions (supplied with PATCH) is longer than the length of the new resource (supplied with PUT) then you may as well just use PUT.

I would say most of the time just use PUT, as it's simpler. Maybe you would use PATCH for a large resource and if the PATCH instructions are small.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, it may be useful to use PUT instead of PATCH in cases where update of 1/more fields might lead to break/corruption of existing resource.
Because in PUT we send the full payload and it will have more information than the fields that we want to update.

We may also have a implementation, wherein for PUT if some fields cause an update of the resource that may have ill consequences. The server can return a valid code with a message.

- I am saying in context of QA, I am not a DEV so I may have limited info :)